# How do you close old instances of BrowserSync when stopping Gulp in Terminal?

Tags: node.js, terminal, gulp, gulp-browser-sync

I'm new to Gulp and BrowserSync, so I've been running gulp and stopping (forced by ctrl + z in terminal) it many times. Every time I start gulp again in terminal, BrowserSync gives me a new PORT number.

I need help removing the old instances of BrowserSync. Is there a command in terminal where I can view and delete old BS instances? Is this even possible?
I started BS at port 3001 (Local) and 3002 (UI) and now I'm at 3018! I want to go back to 3001.

Also, how can I fix my Gulpfile.js code so when I force stop gulp in terminal, browserSync exits Local and UI server instances, so the port number doesn't keep increasing?

My BrowserSync portion in Gulpfile.js is very basic:

```
gulp.task('browser', function () {
  // Serve files from root of this folder
  browserSync({
      server: {
        baseDir: './'
      }
  });
  gulp.watch(['html/*.html', 'js/*.js']).on("change", reload);
});

gulp.task('default', ['styles','browser'], function() {
  gulp.watch('./sass/**/*.scss', ['styles']);
});
```

In my mac Terminal, the latest BS instance is at 30018, and UI happens to be at 3021 (because I recently used bs.server.close(), which closes Local instance, but not the UI instance.

```
[BS] Access URLs:
 --------------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:3018
    External: http://192.168.1.164:3018
 --------------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3021
 UI External: http://192.168.1.164:3021
 --------------------------------------
[BS] Serving files from: ./
^Z
[16]+  Stopped                 gulp
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue is `ctrl + z` only **suspends** the process. (see https://superuser.com/a/262948)

What you want is `ctrl + c`, which will kill it.

First, close your terminal, this should kill any port connections still active in the background.

Next, restart your server, but use `ctrl + c` to exit. You should be able to stop and restart continuously using this method.

Comment: Thanks SteamDev! That did reset the server and BS's port numbers. I thought I had exited and closed out terminal before, but maybe not all the way. So, this time I typed "exit" (twice) then closed out Terminal and reopened it and ran "gulp" on my directory and it worked! Thanks a lot! I'll use ctrl + c next time to kill the whole process.